# Pass text to TextView via Segue

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I'm trying to pass text to `TextView` from other ViewController:

```
    if (segue.identifier == "HomeToDetails") {
        let nav = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let nextVC = nav.topViewController as! DetailsViewController
        nextVC.infoTextView.text = "TESTING"
    }
```

But it crashes:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: show the crash report

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: why u taken the top VC,  DetailsViewController is your next VC correct

Comment: Nitesh this won't work as view has not been loaded for DetailsViewController.Instead send string and set it to textview in viewdidload of DetailsViewController.Hope it helps

Comment: @sanman so there is no way to set text to `TextView` via segue ?

Comment: @Nitesh You need to simply pass the string and then use that string in viewDidLoad to assign text to your textView.

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093716/prepare-for-segue-with-array-xcode-8-0-swift-3-0

Comment: Create a String property in `DetailsViewController`, the `nextVC.thatStringProperty = "TESTING"`, and in `viewDidLoad()` of `DetailsViewController`, do `self.infoTextView.text = self.thatStringProperty`.

Comment: Even I thought of sending it in String but I have lots of TextView on that page and have to pass data to all of them so thought it would be better if I could send it directly.

Comment: Yes nitesh, as view isn't loaded.Instead nextVC.infoTextView.text = "TESTING" use nextVC.someStringVar = "TESTING" and in viewdidload of DetailsViewController  use self.infoTextView.text = self.someStringVar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting text on `UITextField` of `DestinationViewController` is not possible  in the `prepareForSegue:sender`, because all view components of the recently allocated controller are not initialized before the view is loaded (at this time, they are all nil), they only will be when the `DestinationViewController` view is loaded.

You need to use optional variable `infoString` in `DetailsViewController` which you can set in `prepareForSegue` method

```
if (segue.identifier == "HomeToDetails") {
        let nav = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let nextVC = nav.topViewController as! DetailsViewController
        nextVC.infoString = "TESTING"
}
```

in `DetailsViewController.swift`

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

  var infoString: String?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     if let info = infoString {
         self.infoTextView.text = info
     }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if value is nil and you unwrap it, then the app will crash, you should use optional binding to avoid crash.

```
if (segue.identifier == "HomeToDetails") {
    if let nav = segue.destination as? UINavigationController { //should use optional binding to avoid crash
        if let nextVC = nav.topViewController as? DetailsViewController {
            nextVC.infoTextView.text = "TESTING"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
if (segue.identifier == "HomeToDetails") {

    // get a reference to the second view controller
    let secondViewController = segue.destination as! DetailsViewController

    // set a variable in the second view controller with the String to pass
    secondViewController.infoTextView.text = "TESTING"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            if let nav = segue.destination as? UINavigationController {
            if let nextVC = nav.topViewController as? DetailsViewController {
             nextVC.infoTextView.text = "Data you want to pass"
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: `UIViewController` is initiated at this point however it's `UIView` and all child views aren't, therefore `UITextView` will be nil.

Answer (score 0):

this is because when you are assigning value to text view, the text view not initialized that time as viewDidLoad of next class is not called yet. So pass only string, then in viewDidLoad of next class, set the text.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a text directly to `TextView` in another view before it's created.

**First ViewController:**

```
if (segue.identifier == "HomeToDetails") {
let secondViewController = segue.destination as! DetailsViewController
secondViewController.myText = "TESTING"
}
```

**DetailsViewController:**

```
var myText = ""
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
infoTextView.text = myText
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All view components of the  DetailsViewController are not initialized before the view is loaded. You can load that view before assigning values to the components of that view

Consider vC is the view controller which contains the view that you want to load. Then

```
if let _ = vC.view {

      //Assign value here
}
```

Once the view is loaded, we can set the value to the components in that view. In SWIFT 3

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "HomeToDetails" {

        let nav = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let nextVC = nav.topViewController as! DetailsViewController
        if let _ = nextVC.view {
            nextVC.infoTextView.text = "TESTING"
        }
    }
}
```