# how pass array of string from one view to another in swift 3.0 a d xcode 8.2.1

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

how pass array of string from one view to another in swift 3.0 & xcode 8.2.1.I pass simple data from one view to another but array can't send.
What can i do? Tell me someone please that i pass it

Comment: can you please show me your code?

Comment: please try this tutorial 
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-passing-data-between-controllers-in-swift--cms-27151

Comment: i remove it because i don't understand it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Storyboard then you need to do it inside the

```
PrepareForSegue()
```

otherwise if you're doing it in code you can either make the array of strings a parameter of your constructor method, or assign the variable to your view controller as a property after constructing it.

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? Are you using Storyboard or Code?

Comment: yes i used storyboard

Comment: Here's your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093716/prepare-for-segue-with-array-xcode-8-0-swift-3-0
If it works, please mark my answer as accepted :)

Comment: it occur error  "print(newString) variable used within its own initial value "

Comment: can you show me your code? you are trying to print newString while it hasnt been initialized or something

Comment: i am new to swift therefore